# Cannot connect to Tomcat using own IP address

Tags: tomcat, ip

Created an EC2 with linux distro, successful installed the tomcat10 on the machine and its active.

When i try accessing tomcat through my own ip address http://3.10.213.82:8080 it does not connect.

I have checked my firewalls there no restrictions applied

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "my own IP address", but I assume you mean the public IP address of the EC2 instance you have created. In order to reach TCP port 8080 on that machine, you need to have a valid an "inbound rule" for that EC2 instance's security group. One way to do this is via the AWS admin console (web site). The rule needs to specifically allow access from "My PC" - the PC you are using to browse to your Tomcat's web site. It's similar to the process for giving yourself SSH access (to the EC2 instance's command line),

Comment: See [Authorize inbound traffic for your Linux instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html). In your case, you need a rule for TCP and port 8080, using your PC's public IP address as the source. Having said all that... I think this question is off-topic on SO because it is not about software development, but about configuring AWS EC2.

Comment: @andrewJames absolutey amazing the way yiou have explained this to me. For some time i was confused between the difference between Inbound and Outbound, your explanation was spot and has worked a treat. Well done. Created an Inbound rule and solved the proble m

Comment: Thank you. Glad it helped! You are welcome to write an [answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), to help future visitors. You can explain in your own words what you did to fix the problem, and feel free to use my comments also, if you want to. (But it's possible this question may be closed...)